# Quantum Annealing on IBMQ using Qiskit-Pulse

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, optimization, annealing, qiskit-runtime

Qiskit-Pulse is the analog level control SDK of IBMQ hardware. Is it possible to implement an adiabatic annealing protocol/algorithm on IBMQ hardware using Qiskit-Pulse?

Not asking about QAOA, which I know is similar to adiabatic annealing but variational in nature.